# Django runonce-per-db flag?

Tags: django, django-signals, django-database

What is the Django "runonce-per-db" flag?

I see it mentioned in [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/django-developers/browse_thread/thread/ff0e2a8ecded4c2d), but cannot find any documentation for it.

Comment: How utterly bizarre to see you here man! That made my day. Hope all is well :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's django code. `runonce` doesn't appear in the source.

> To implement this we attach to the post_syncdb, and set a  runonce-per-db flag (since it seems to be the
>   only available signal)

He's just saying he needs to set a flag (which he's referring to as runonce-per-db) because `post_syncdb` is emitted for every app and presumably his code needs to fire only once.